# Meaning of "clot" in the following sentence

Tags: british-english

I've searched all of the reasonable sources for a meaning of *clot* as the word appears in the following sentence.  I've also tracked down a couple of people who shear sheep and neither of them was able to help me.  Before going to the effort described above, I assumed that *clot* meant un-carded, unwashed wool, but there does not appear to be any text that supports my suspicion.  Here is the sentence:

> The wool produced by the pasturing of sheep was needed in ever-increasing amounts for the manufacture of clot.

After more-or-less coming to the conclusion that *clot* was a typo and that the correct word was *cloth* I got some push-back from editors who based their opinion on context.  Anybody know what is meant by *clot*?

The sentence comes from an historical account of enclosure in 16th century England.

Comment: No need to assume a typo; in the 16th century orthography wasn't quite as fixed as it is today. "Clot" is certainly no further than the "clout" in *Ne're cast a clout till May be out*.

Comment: The writing was 20th century, not 16th, so my question (and the usage) is in a more-or-less contemporary context.

Comment: @bye That _clout_ is a different word from _cloth_. The vowel has been written in countless ways, but I've never come across th being written as t, even in older texts. If _cloth_ were written _clot_, even in the 16th century, I'd say it's almost certainly through a typo (though it is now clear that this text is not actually from back then).

Comment: Clotted cream is not made with wool. And one would not manufacture clotted wool. Wool cloth is probably correct. Is there more to the text then that posted?

Answer (score 5):

A **clot** is a lumpy thing - most often heard of as a **blood clot** that clogs an artery or **mud clots** that you scrape off of your boot.

While clot may have some deep meaning in 16th century England, the argument that it a typo for cloth is pretty compelling.

Comment: Most of [the `KL-` words  in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf) refer to some sense of "contiguous; connected; together", so it's not terribly surprising that such word clusters as _clot, clout,_ and _cloth_ can be used more or less at will for varieties of the same thing.

Comment: That isn't 100 percent *clear* to me. But thanks for *clueing* me in.

Comment: @JohnLawler, thanks for the great link.  You have, again, amazed me.  I am off to bake klugel.

Comment: And thanks for explaining to me why "clot" sounds so good to me.